# copying files from recycle bin

Tags: powershell, recycle-bin

Here ([Listing files in recycle bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716521/listing-files-in-recycle-bin)) I've found a @Smile4ever post saying how to get the original location for the files in recycle bin:

```
(New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace(0x0a).Items()
|select @{n="OriginalLocation";e={$_.ExtendedProperty("{9B174B33-40FF-11D2-A27E-00C04FC30871} 2")}},Name
| export-csv -delimiter "\" -path C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\recycleBinFiles.txt -NoTypeInformation

(gc C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\recycleBinFiles.txt | select -Skip 1)
| % {$_.Replace('"','')}
| set-content C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\recycleBinFiles.txt
```

I'd like to copy them somewhere (in case I've been told that some of them were not to be deleted and someone empty recycle bin).

Here (https://superuser.com/questions/715673/batch-script-move-files-from-windows-recycle-bin) I've found a @gm2 post for copying them

```
$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application  
$recycleBin = $shell.Namespace(0xA) #Recycle Bin  
$recycleBin.Items() | %{Copy-Item $_.Path ("C:\Temp\{0}" -f $_.Name)}
```

And they work fine, but I'd need something more.

I don't know anything about powershell, but what I'd like to do would be:
for each file in Recycle bin to create its original location folder in the backup folder C:\Temp and to copy the file there (so I won't have the problem of more files with the same name).

And then to zip that C:\Temp.

Is there a way foir doing it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
# Set a folder path INSIDE the C:\Temp folder to collect the files and folders
$outputPath = 'C:\Temp\RecycleBackup'
# afterwards, a zip file is created in 'C:\Temp' with filename 'RecycleBackup.zip'

$shell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application  
$recycleBin = $shell.Namespace(0xA)
$recycleBin.Items() | ForEach-Object {
    # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shellfolderitem-extendedproperty
    $originalPath = $_.ExtendedProperty("{9B174B33-40FF-11D2-A27E-00C04FC30871} 2")
    # get the root disk from that original path
    $originalRoot = [System.IO.Path]::GetPathRoot($originalPath)

    # remove the root from the OriginalPath
    $newPath = $originalPath.Substring($originalRoot.Length)

    # change/remove the : and \ characters in the root for output
    if ($originalRoot -like '?:\*') {  
        # a local path.  X:\ --> X
        $newRoot = $originalRoot.Substring(0,1)
    }
    else {                             
        # UNC path.  \\server\share --> server_share
        $newRoot = $originalRoot.Trim("\") -replace '\\', '_'   
        #"\"# you can remove this dummy comment to restore syntax highlighting in SO
    }

    $newPath = Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath "$newRoot\$newPath"
    # if this new path does not exist yet, create it
    if (!(Test-Path -Path $newPath -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item -Path $newPath -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    # copy the file or folder with its original name to the new output path
    Copy-Item -Path $_.Path -Destination (Join-Path -Path $newPath -ChildPath $_.Name) -Force -Recurse
}

# clean up the Com object when done
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($shell) | Out-Null
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
$shell = $null
```

**The following code needs PowerShell version 5**

```
# finally, create a zip file of this RecycleBackup folder and everything in it.
# append a '\*' to the $outputPath variable to enable recursing the folder
$zipPath = Join-Path -Path $outputPath -ChildPath '*'
$zipFile = '{0}.zip' -f $outputPath.TrimEnd("\")
#"\"# you can remove this dummy comment to restore syntax highlighting in SO

# remove the zip file if it already exists
if(Test-Path $zipFile -PathType Leaf) { Remove-item $zipFile -Force }
Compress-Archive -Path $zipPath -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath $zipFile -Force
```

**To create a zip file in PowerShell below version 5**

If you do not have PowerShell 5 or up, the `Compress-Archive` is not available.
To create a zip file from the `C:\Temp\RecycleBackup` you can do this instead:

```
$zipFile = '{0}.zip' -f $outputPath.TrimEnd("\")
#"\"# you can remove this dummy comment to restore syntax highlighting in SO

# remove the zip file if it already exists
if(Test-Path $zipFile -PathType Leaf) { Remove-item $zipFile -Force }
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'
[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($outputPath, $zipFile)
```

Of course, you can also use a third party software like 7Zip for this. There are plenty of examples on the net how to use that in Powershell like for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25287994/running-7-zip-from-within-a-powershell-script)

**As per your last request to remove the 'RecycleBackup' folder after the zip is created**

```
Remove-Item -Path $outputPath -Recurse -Force
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you so much!
On my pc it works perfectly, while on the pc where I need it, it creates the backup, but while zipping I get the error:

Comment: Compress-Archive : The term 'Compress-Archive' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At C:\XXX\backup_deleted_files.ps1:48 char:1
+ Compress-Archive -Path $zipPath -CompressionLevel Optimal -DestinationPath $zipF ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Compress-Archive:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

I created the zip manually without problems

Comment: what is missing?
Thanks!

Comment: one last thing:
once the zip file is created (but only if it's created) would be useful to delete (permanently, not moving it in recycle bin) the C:\Temp\RecycleBackup, for not occupying too many GB...
Thanks!

Comment: @solquest I have updated my answer. Apparently you are working with a Powershell version below 5.0 (`Compress-Archive` is available as of PowerShell version 5), so I added alternative code. I have also added code to remove the C:\Temp\RecycleBackup folder afterwards.