# How to restore specific or last deleted files from recycle bin using Powershell / Node.js?

Tags: node.js, powershell, cmd

I have an app that can run Node.js and Powershell commands (Electron) and I'm trying to figure out the best (or any) way to restore from recycle bin either:

- The last deleted items
- or items deleted in specific time period (e.g. last 5 minutes)
- or (preferable) specific paths

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56931249/copying-files-from-recycle-bin) but I don't have enough Powershell experience to apply it for my case.

So far I only figured a way to list recycle bin items:

```
function RestoreItems () {
  $recycleBin = (New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application).NameSpace(0x0a);
  $recycleBin.Items() | ForEach-Object {
    # unfinished code:
    $originalPath = $_.ExtendedProperty(...)
    Copy-Item $_.Path ($originalPath)
  }
}

RestoreItems -Paths ['C:\test\1', 'C:\test\2']
```

Which outputs all recycle bin items with all the properties that I need (name and date).

Assuming that I have an array of file names that I need to restore, how do I do that?

Comment: Have you found the answer yet?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I haven't.